# @user is not autocompleted anymore in comments

Tags: support, status-bydesign, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

I noticed that the autocompletion for @user is not working anymore when answering in a comment (there was a box to click on showing the users on top of the @ sign before).

So I am not sure if the user gets my message. Is this a problem with my browser (maybe it isn't working since I installed firefox 13) or is this a change on the website?

Comment: I think a [meta-tag:status-bydesign] is in order...

Comment: All of the details regarding that functionality are here: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I was searching for a similar question, but didn't found one (maybe my English is not good enough to search something that I cannot even describe in my mother tongue ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only autocomplete when you are not conversing with the OP and when you and the OP are not the only persons talking.

Comment: +1 thanks. so the OP will receive my comment without any @OP I learned.